# Assign variables to each value in Excel Sheet cell separated by Commas

Tags: c#, excel

I'm having troubles grabbing values in an excel sheet for cells containing multiple sets of data separated by commas. For example, if cell B24 contains '100,200,400,900,1200', would it be possible to assign each of those values to a specific variable?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use string[] words = cellB24.Split(',');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string text = "100,200,400,900,1200";
string[] splitedText = text.Split(',');
```

`text` variable contains the cell B45 value. Then use split method to split.